# how to randomize the output of a text file

Tags: python, tkinter, ftp, textbox

what im trying to do is pull a random line of text from a file on a ftp server. what the code is doing now is just pulling the first line of text from the file. how do i randomize it to where everytime the hit the button its outputs a random line.

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from ftplib import FTP
from io import StringIO
from tkinter import messagebox
import random
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame): 
   def __init__(self, master = None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)

    self.master = master

    self.init_window()

def init_window(self):

    self.master.title("COD:WWII Codes")

    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    codeButton = Button(self, text = "Generate Code", command = self.generatecode)

    codeButton.place(x=75, y=75)

def generatecode(self):

    ftp=FTP("python123.atwebpages.com")
    ftp.login(user="2353790", passwd="monster95")
    ftp.cwd("python123.atwebpages.com")
    filename = "codes.txt"
    file=open(filename, "r")

    self.Cont = Text(self,width=60,height=40)
    self.Cont.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2)
    self.Cont.insert("1.0", file.read(6))  #output



root=Tk()
root.geometry("300x250")

app = Window(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How big is the file you're reading? The solution might be different if it's only a few megabytes versus several gigabytes.

Comment: as of now its just 1kb for testing purposes. but it wont be anywhere near a gigabyte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the amount of data is small, I would read the entire file and split it on newlines so that you have a list of lines. You can then use `random.randint` to pick a number between zero and the number of lines in the file. You can then use that number to get that line.

Comment: how do i input that into my coding? im still new to python lol learning from the webs.